# Application closes after user input

Tags: c#

I'm trying to construct a game on the console, but after a player is asked to input either A or B, the application closes. It shouldn't!

I have two classes. This one is Window.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyAdventure
{
public class Window
{
    public static void theWindow()
    {
        string playerInput = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("You approach the window, and you look outside.");
        Console.WriteLine("You see lots of trees, but you can't put a name on the location.");
        Console.WriteLine("You pull the handle on the window in an attempt to open it.");
        Console.WriteLine("You succeed and escape the room through the window.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nAs you look around, you still don't know where you are.");
        Console.WriteLine("You suddenly hear someone approaching from behind.");
        Console.WriteLine("You turn around and see a man drenched in blood.\nHe's pale, and he looks sick. He moans at you.");
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nWhat do you do?\nA. Ask if he's alright and who he is\nB. Try to find something tod defend yourself with, just in case...");

        if (playerInput.StartsWith("A", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You ask if he's alright, but he doesn't respond.\nYou ask then who he is, but he still doesn't respond.");
            Console.WriteLine("Before you even get to think, he lunges towards you in a surprise!");
            Console.WriteLine("He holds on to you and tries to bite you.\nUnfortunately, he manages to do so and takes a chunk from your neck.");
            Console.WriteLine("As he's consuming you, you scream aloud in pain as you slowly fade away...");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nGAME OVER!\nUnfortunately, your choices got you killed.\nPlease, restart the game and try again.");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n(Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        else if (playerInput.StartsWith("B", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            //Insert next class and method here...
        }



    }
}
}
```

My other class is Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyAdventure
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("You cannot feel your body. You don't know where you are.\nThe room you're in is dark. You cannot see much.");
        Console.WriteLine("You decide to stand up, and take a look around. You see a door and a window.\nWhich do you check out first?");
        Console.WriteLine("A. Window\nB. Door");

        string playerInput = Console.ReadLine();

        if (playerInput.StartsWith("A", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            Window.theWindow();
        }
        else if (playerInput.StartsWith("B", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("You chose the door.");
            Console.WriteLine("\nUnfortunately, the door is locked.\nYou cannot leave through the door.");
            Console.WriteLine("You turn to the window.");
            Console.WriteLine("\n(Press Enter to continue...)");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Window.theWindow();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
}
```

Could anyone please help? Big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you have Environment.Exit(0); in there? When Player A makes his/her move then this is the last line of code in that condition... makes sense that it should close no?

Comment: Oh that is because the player chooses option A, which is the wrong choice and then the game closes because he/she loses. But when the player chooses option B, the game should continue. The game closes no matter what the player does. Even if the player chooses A, it should at least display the message before the game closes. Do you see what I mean? EDIT: I even tried to remove the Environment.Exit(0); and it still closes as soon as the player makes a choice.

Comment: Of course it closes, there is nothing left to execute. Your best bet is to capture use input in a loop as per the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

Currently when input string is read the console window closes because there is no next code. What you should do is create a while loop above your logic that will read input key until Q is pressed for example.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string playerInput = "";
        while(playerInput!="q"){
            //your code
            playerInput = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```